# How to search LDAP using more than one parameter?

Tags: java, ldap

I am working on a search application. Using LDAP as the data source.

I have 6 different fields to search by.

At the moment I am just able to search by one field.

i call that method when I search by "loc" field.

How can search the LDAP using all 6 fields at once ? without repeating any codes ..??

Comment: Please show some code, preferably a SSCCE. Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide search predicates thus:

```
(&(objectclass=person)(cn=brian))
```

which searches for a person `objectclass` *and* `cn` of brian.

[This link](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/LDAP/LDAP_Resources/SEARCH_Using_Search_Syntax.shtml) has more search help (see the section marked *Filters*)

Answer (score 0):

You have to build an [LDAP Filter](http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm) string

For searcing on location and lastname your filter string should look like:

> (&(location=yourlocation)(lastname=yourlastname))

Comment: Sorry there is a problem, my above method is in a separate class, and my getters and setters of the fields are also in a different class, how I can I call those getters in the ldap method class...any suggestions ?

Comment: Pass the other object in as a parameter? But I have to warn you, I'm not a java guy...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/). Do not use JNDI for new code.

A search consists of the following parameters at a minimum:

- A base object from which the search begins
- A scope indicating the depth of the search: `base` object only, `one` level below the base object, and `subtree` which is all objects subordinate to and including the base object
- A filter used to narrow down the candidates that match the other parameters. A filter is constructed from a sequence of  attribute value assertions which take the form `attributeDescription=attributeValue`.
- A list of attributes to retrieve from the entries that match the above parameters.

There are additional parameters such as time limit, size limit, dereferencing a so forth. See the links below for complete discussions of LDAP operations such as search.

#### see also

- [LDAP Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)
- [Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)